# Deserialize JSON document to MongoDB Mappd Classes

Tags: c#, json, mongodb-.net-driver

I am having hard time trying to understand how to use the MongoDB Discriminator in both C# (Server side) and Javascript/JSON (Client side) in order to allow me to deserialized a javascript object to a predefined Class with properties that by themselves are Classes.

For example:

**C# Class**

```
public Class Book
{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public List<Chapter> Chapters {get; set;}

}

[BsonDiscriminator("chapters")
public Class Chapter
{
 public int num {get; set; }
 public string name {get; set; }
}
```

**JSON string**

```
  { "name": "book1", "chapters": [ {"num":1, "name":"name1"}, {"num":2, 
    "name":"name2"]
```

I want the chapters array on the JSON to be deserlized to match the `List<Chapter>  Chapters` property in the Book Class.

In my application the Chapter class might have another class as a property, but I wanted to keep it simple.

I tried to add `"_t": ["chapters"] "` into the root document but that' didn't worked out.

How can I use Discriminators in order to achieve the type of serialization? -- thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve that doesn't work? Discriminators are used mostly for polymorphism...

Comment: @I3arnon Hi, is there other way to solve this?

Comment: Well, what is the actual problem? What are you not able to do?